# Unable to get 2 images to expand to fill the parent div

Tags: html, css, image

What I am trying to do is create a page that has a table with 2 columns. The column on the left has a number of data displayed (this part works fine) and the column on the right will have div that displays 2 images side by side (this also works). The problem is that the images in the right div will not expand to fill the full height of the left table column. If I look at things in the debugger I can see that my left table column is (for example) 440px in height. However, the right div is always 300px in height. Since my img is 45x300px I guess the div is somehow inheriting from this. I have been using CSS for a while now but would not consider myself an expert so I really think there is something regarding how the height is being inherited that I am missing. The html for this looks something like the following:

```html
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="left-outer">
                <!-- left side content goes here -->
                <p>Test 1....</p>
                ...
            </td>
            <td class="right-outer">
                <div class="right-outer-2images">
                    <div class="right-outer-2images-img1">
                        <img border="0" src="http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/gif/fish.png" alt="Report Image Bar" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="right-outer-2images-img2">
                        <img border="0" src="http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/gif/czoch.png" alt="Report Image Bar" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.left-outer {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
    width: 20%;
}
.right-outer {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    width: 80%;
    /*display: inline-flex;
     justify-content: flex-start;*/
    height: 100%;
}
.right-outer-2images {
    float: left;
    height: 635px;  /* This works but is not ideal */
    /*height: 100%;*/ /* This does not work but I believe should */
    width: 98%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: blue;
    /*vertical-align: text-top;*/
}
.right-outer-2images-img1 {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height:100%;
    /*border-style: solid;*/
    border-color: orange;
}
.right-outer-2images-img2 {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    /*border-style: solid;*/
    border-color: yellow;
}
.right-outer-2images-img1 img,
.right-outer-2images-img2 img {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

So the height of left-outer (table column) contents will always be larger than the images and I would like the images to be stretched to be the same height and displayed in the right-outer table column. With the CSS example above if I explicitly set the height of the **right-outer-2images** div to the actual height then everything seems to work but if I set the height to 100% (or inherit) it does not work. I have put together a sample in jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/a98w683u/) please have a look and let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: When you say that you want the images in the right column to "expand to fill the full height of the left column", do you want it to scale proportionately? Otherwise the image is distorted...is that how you intend it to be?

Comment: The images I've used will get distorted. I couldn't upload my own images so I just found some that was already on the web as examples. The first image I will use shouldn't get distorted because it will never get big enough to be distorted. The 2nd image will consist of a number of thumbnails that again will keep it from being distorted. But I currently cannot get the images to expand to fill the parent div without knowing the height of the parent div which I will not know prior to displaying the image.

Comment: Try `.whatever-class img { height: 100% !important; width: 100% important;`

Comment: @Remy, adding the !important doesn't work for me. I still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because a height is never defined for your table cell or your table. Therefore your `height:100%` declarations do not know what to be 100% of. If you set a height on the `.right-outer` declaration it will work:

[DEMO EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/rH5qm1oq0doSkFmhTpwt?p=preview)

Changes to these 3 declarations are needed:

```
.right-outer {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px; /* this is more of a starting height as the left column will stretch it  */
}
.right-outer-2images {
    float: left;
    height: 100%; /* don't forget to change this back to 100% */
    width: 98%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: blue;
}
.right-outer-2images-img1 {
    height:100%; /* Updated; add this back in */
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    border-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: Thx, J.C but it doesn't seem to do what I need. The 2 images are still no being displayed at the full height of the left-outer div.

Comment: Ok, my mistake. I thought you just wanted the right image to stretch full height. If you add back in the `height:100%` to `.right-out-2images-img1` then both images will stretch to 100%. I updated my example to see this in action.

Comment: Hmm, still not what I need. I need the blue box and it's images to stretch to match the red box. However, still maintaining the 20%/80% left-outer/right-outer ratio. I am wondering if I need to use JS to do this. The problem is I believe that the JS will need to kick in before the page is rendered so whatever value is returned for the height in the controller would probably be wrong anyway (i.e. using $( '.right.outer' ).height();). Is there some way to register a watcher on the .right-outer then get the size once it has already been rendered? Use that to update .right-outer-2images then redo.

Comment: Can you post an mockup image of exactly what you want? I'm having a difficult time understanding what you are after.

Comment: sorry been busy... I'll try to put something together and attach it. I've got an important deadline for 4pm tomorrow so have been focused on that the last day or 2.

Comment: Hi J.C, sorry for the delay... I've placed a mockup here: http://framebox.org/rUEL-TtyNIT. You can see that there is a right image that stretches to the full height of the 2nd div then there is another group of images that are to represent thumbnails. There can be 0 or more thumbnails. What I need is for both those divs to expand to the max size of the left div. If the thumbnails region becomes larger than the left div then it shouldn't increase the overall height but instead become a scrollable area but without a scroll bar. I hope this is more clear.